# Centering 3 child divs, all 100% width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

So I have a parent div (100% width) and in it, 3 child divs (also 100% width). How would I set the "default displayed div" to the 2nd child such that the left div would be off screen to the left and the right div would be offscreen to the right?

[here is my code so far](https://jsfiddle.net/dhq0mnm2/).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" class="fixed-container">
        <div id="left-wrap" class="moving">
            <div id="left-prev" class="prev content-container">prev</div>
            <div id="left-next" class="next content-container">next</div>
            <div id="left-cur" class="cur content-container">cur</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="fixed-container">
        <div id="right-wrap" class="moving">
            <div id="right-prev" class="prev content-container">prev</div>
            <div id="right-next" class="next content-container">next</div>
            <div id="right-cur" class="cur content-container">cur</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*RESET*/
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*page wrapper style and layout*/
#wrapper {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background:white;
}

/*left and right fixed container
---------------------------------*/

/*STYLES*/
.fixed-container {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
#left {
    background:#99FF99;
}

/*LAYOUT*/
#left {
    float:left;
}
#right {
    float:right;
}

/*back, current and next div wrapper*/
.moving {
    height:100%;
    width:300%;
    position:absolute;
}

/*back, current and next containers
------------------------------------*/

/*STYLES*/
.content-container {
    height:100%;
    width:33.33%;
}
.next {
    background:#fa342f;
}
.cur {
    background:#a82f33;
}

/*LAYOUT*/
.prev {
    float:left;
}
.next {
    float:right;
}
.cur {
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

---

Basically I want both left and right divs to show $(".cur") on page load. I've tried using the scrollTo plugin but only the left div scrolls ([as seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/dhq0mnm2/2/)). How would I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function in the fiddle ([checked here](https://jsfiddle.net/dhq0mnm2/3/)) can be fixed like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fixed-container").each(
        function(i) {
          $(this).scrollTo($('.cur').eq(i), {axis: "x"});
        }
    );  
});
```

You were centering just one wrapper and each has a div with class 'cur'.